# to return the value of iframe inside the body using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wysihat

I'm using the wysihat-engine on my jsp. It works well, but when I tried to add a preview feature that is suppose to read from the on-fly created iFrame and put it's value inside the hidden preview div, it couldn't read the iframe's included html. 
Any work-around for this? Thanks!
In this example i want to return the value inside the body using jquery

the following iFrame is not written inside my jsp, but it is attached to a div by WYSihat.js file:

```
<iframe id="iframeId" class="abc">
   <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <br>
        some text here 
        </br>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

How to return "some text here" and pass it to the following function:
Hint, this iFrame has been created on fly by the WYSiHat.js file, as it is not hard written inside my jsp page

```
function preview() {
    alert("hi"+$('iframe.editor').contents().find('body').text());
}
```

Comment: Your iframe doesn't seem to have the class `editor`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description is certainly confusing, however to access the contents of an `iframe` you must use the `contents()` method on a jQuery object:

```
$('iframe.abc').contents().find('body').text();
```

Here we have selected the `iframe` itself, then got its contents. From there we can search the iframe's DOM normally using `find()`.

For more information on the contents method see the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

Comment: I re-edited my question, would you please take a look on it. The code you provided didn't work for me :(

Comment: @Ali You've accepted the answer does this mean your problem is resolved? My only comment would be the one @lonesomeday gave n your question.

Comment: +1 Just to added to this answer. This only works if the contents of the iframe are in the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

To find an element inside an `iframe`, you can use the jQuery function [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), which returns the `document` object of the `iframe`:

```
$('iframe.abc').contents().find('body').html();
```